# Trying to show selected categories in a multi select form input

Tags: craft3, categories, form, user-profile

I have a users form, which they can select their occupations. They can choose multiple values from a multi-select input.

Occupations are categories that are related to users profile.

Here in this code, i can get the values and submit witout any problem,but i cannot show as selected when user returns to form. They should see thier previous selections.

```
{% set categories = craft.categories.group('occupation').all() %}  
<input type="hidden" name="fields[occupation][]" value="">
<select multiple name="fields[occupation][]" class="selectpicker" >

{% for category in categories %}        
  {% set selected = currentUser.occupation.all()  %}    
  <option value="{{ category.id }}" {% if category.id == selected  %} selected{% endif %} > {{ category.title }} </option>
{% endfor %}
```

How can i access to selected arrays id value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `currentUser.occupation.all()` your `selected` variable is an objet so your conditional `{% if category.id == selected %}` will never pass as you are checking if `category.id` equals an object.

For this to work, first get the ids of the `currentUser` occupations:

`{% set selected = currentUser.occupation.ids() %}`

Which would return an array of ids (key/value pairs) then you compare doing:

`{% if category.id in selected|values %}`

So in full:

```twig
    <select multiple name="fields[occupation][]" class="selectpicker" >
        {% for category in categories %}        
        {% set selected = currentUser.occupation.ids() %}
          <option value="{{ category.id }}" {% if category.id in selected|values %} selected{% endif %} > {{ category.title }} </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
```